# Dynamic conversion c#

Tags: c#, types

I know it has been asked several times but I'm having very hard time understanding the `<T>` concept.

I'm working on a custom GridView and I want to set the `Cell.Value` property upon `CellUpdate` event. the problem is that in most cases I will have to take a string from the cell's control input while I have no idea how to 'dynamically' convert (in elegant way) this `String` to the original object which in this case is represented in `_Value` as object.

Hope any of this make some sense, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the `Type` of the original object (like int, float, CustomType, etc.)

Comment: you mean you dont have any idea whats the type of the original value stored in the cell?

Comment: The Cell.Value is of type onject so I can run Cell.Value.GetType() to get the type I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic (`<T>`) and Dynamic are two opposite concepts. Generics should be known at compile-time and dynamic are resolved at runtime. So if you know the type (`<T>`) dynamically only at runtime you cannot invoke a generic method unless you use reflection.

Depending on your specific requirements and code you are dealing with there might be different solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I will only know the type at runtime. the only solution I can think of is running hundreds of if(object.GetType().ToString() == "System.Int32")

Comment: @Esh, there might be other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Generics and reflections are very hard together and are not recommended to use. If you get to a point where you want to use both together, it is usually a bad design to begin with. Even if it is not a bad design, consider alternatives which would not require you to take this course of action.

I had some experience with generics and reflection and I don't recommend it one bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy, automatic way to do it. You can relatively easily convert between primitives (i.e. types that implement [IConvertable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)), using [Convert.ChangeType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx).
But otherwise you're on your own.

For example, this is a crude, but possible way of doing it:

```
object v = myCell.Value;
if(v is int)
{
    int vInt = (int)v;
    // ...
}
else if(v is string)
{
    string vStr = (string)v;
    // ...
}
else if(v is MyClass)
{
    MyClass vMyClass = (MyClass)v;
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Note that in case of reference types, it's preferable to use `as` and then check for `null` - I didn't use it above because it leads to ugly code, a lot of local variables, and I prefer to avoid that and I rather pay the performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your CellUpdate event has the equivalent of an (Object sender) ?
You should be able to do a cast of the sender to your control and use the properties from that point.
It's hard to provide an exact example since I don't know how your type is set up but it could be something similar to ((GridViewCell)sender).Text;
There are probably many ways to do this but it's going to depend a lot upon your specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use TypeConveters, either the built-in for System types, or write your own for custom types, e.g:

```
 TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
 if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))...
```

Take a look at my answer to another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021115/determine-type-from-given-string-input/4022123#4022123)